# mailto php removing new line characters

Tags: php, mailto

I'm using a mailto link to send e-mail with a php string variable inside it as follows:

```
'Would you like to E-mail stakeholders? <a class="emailLink" href="mailto:stakeholders?subject=Alert '.$ticket.'&body=Experience:  %0D%0A'.$exp.'">Review and Send!</a><br><br>';
```

I discovered that in the e-mail client it prints it out like:

```
Experience:  
Th Experience should contain:\r\n\r\nImpact\r\nHow to replicate\r\nComprehensive notes
```

So I tried:

```
$charactersToRemove = array("\r\n","\n","\r");
$replaceWith = "%0D%0A";
$exp = str_replace($charactersToRemove,$replaceWith,$exp);
```

Which doesn't seem to make a difference...Can someone tell me why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post more of your code to show how `$exp` was assigned it's value?

I've edited out my answer until I can provide better help.

EDIT: Can you seriously try using `"\r\n"` with `\"` to escape `"`'s instead, just in case PHP is somehow localizing `%0D$0A` in your HTML output?  What does the source of your page look like?

Comment: I'm not sure if your suggestion really is in line with my problem.  he issue i'm facing is with the `$exp` printed inside the e-mail client which is retrieved from the db.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I'm looking for a better answer for you now.

Comment: so looks like `\r\n` fixed the problem. Thanks for illuminating the issue.